# Potassium tetraoxalate preparation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, recrystallization

> How is potassium tetraoxalate produced industrially? In fact How I can limit the reaction of $\ce{H2C2O4}$ and $\ce{KOH}$?
>
> Or is there any other route for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In fact How I can limit the reaction of H2C2O4 and KOH?

If you are to react potassium hydroxide with oxalic acid in 1:1 mole ratio, you will get [potassium hydrogenoxalate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_hydrogenoxalate) ($\ce{KHC2O4}$). Its hydrate form exist at a specific temperature range. This salt contains the [hydrogenoxalate anion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogenoxalate) and hence known as acid potassium oxalate. But if you add an excess of concentrated oxalic acid and maintaining a temperature of below $\pu{50 °C}$, the much less soluble potassium tetraoxalate ($\ce{K+[C2HO4]^−.C2H2O4}$) forms and precipitates out of solution since it is sparingly soluble in water. So your target compound depends on the concentration of the reagents and the temperature.

> Or is there any other route for this purpose?

There is [a patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2033097A/en) which claims to have made potassium oxalate from potassium formate.